# Linux shell show [section] with grep command

Tags: sed, grep

I need to parse multiple files from asterisk to get informations that refer to same objects but are stored in different positions (ideally I would like to get the sectionname reference).

Now I look for a specific string with:

```
    grep -OPTIONS /DIRECTORY -e SEARCHSTRING

OPTIONS
       -r, --recursive
              Read all files under each directory, recursively, following symbolic links only if they are on the command line.  This is equivalent to the -d recurse option.

       -n, --line-number
              Prefix each line of output with the 1-based line number within its input file.  (-n is specified by POSIX.)
```

i.e. seach string "outrt-5" in folder /etc/asterisk:

```
# grep -rn /etc/asterisk/ -e  outrt-5 
/etc/asterisk/extensions_additional.conf:4462:include => outrt-5 ; test
/etc/asterisk/extensions_additional.conf:4662:[outrt-5] ; test
/etc/asterisk/extensions_additional.conf:4663:include => outrt-5-custom
/etc/asterisk/extensions_additional.conf:4677:;--== end of [outrt-5] ==--;
```

Now I've retrieved the single line number reference and filenames.

How can I retrieve all the rows in the section or at least the nameofsection (a section is delimited by [nameofsection] )?

Is sed - stream editor for filtering and transforming text the best option?

```
# STARTROW=4460
# NEXTROW=4462
# ENDROW=4462

sed -n "${STARTROW}, ${NEXTROW} p; ${ENDROW} q" /etc/asterisk/extensions_additional.conf
```

i.e. /etc/asterisk/extensions_additional.conf  section near line:4462:

```
[outbound-allroutes]
include => outbound-allroutes-custom
include => outrt-5 ; test
```

So now you can see that **outrt-5** is inside **outbound-allroutes**

Is there a way to get as search result:

```
> /etc/asterisk/extensions_additional.conf:4462:include => outrt-5 ;[outbound-allroutes]
```

?

Comment: Ignore the recursion for the moment; write a script that works on a single file and get the recursive descent with `find`.

Comment: Any time you are thinking about `grep | sed`, the answer you want is almost certainly trivial with `awk`.

Comment: eg, you can almost certainly filter out a section with `awk '/\[nameofsection\]/' RS=`

Comment: Why is "with grep" part of this question? You're ruling out the better answers, which don't use grep at all, for no obvious reason.

Comment: @miken32 why did you remove the asterisk tag? It seems very relevant to a question about parsing asterisk configuration files.

Comment: @jhnc it's a question about searching a text file, a sample of which should have been provided in the question. The fact that it's an Asterisk configuration doesn't make the question about Asterisk.

Comment: Really there are probably 95 duplicates on how to pull out a section from an ini-style text file. If you want a true Asterisk solution, try `asterisk -x "dialplan show outrt-5"`

Comment: @miken32 yes, I'd definitely let the system do the work where possible, instead of trying to parse manually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I generally use `sed` for simple block selection scripts. For example -

```
$: cat file # note that there is NO blank line at the end
[outbound-allroutes]
include => outbound-allroutes-custom
include => outrt-1 ; test first block

[outbound-allroutes]
include => outbound-allroutes-custom
include => nope-5 ; test

[outbound-allroutes]
include => outbound-allroutes-custom
include => outrt-2 ; test embedded block

[outbound-allroutes]
include => outbound-allroutes-custom
include => nope-5 ; test

[outbound-allroutes]
include => outbound-allroutes-custom
include => nope-5 ; test

[outbound-allroutes]
include => outbound-allroutes-custom
include => outrt-3 ; test last/END block
```

I'm going to grab every block that has `outrt`. You can modify the logic a bit to fit your exact needs.

```
$: cat tst
sed -n '
 /\[.*\]/,/^[[:space:]]*$/{
   /\[.*\]/{h; n;}
   /^[[:space:]]*$/{ H; x; /outrt/{p; n;} }
   H;
 }
 ${ x; /outrt/p }
' file

$: ./tst
[outbound-allroutes]
include => outbound-allroutes-custom
include => outrt-1 ; test first block

[outbound-allroutes]
include => outbound-allroutes-custom
include => outrt-2 ; test embedded block

[outbound-allroutes]
include => outbound-allroutes-custom
include => outrt-3 ; test last/END block
```

This is GNU `sed`. If you don't have that we'll need to make some modifications.

`grep` is good, but it doesn't really allow complex logic that defines arbitrary length multiline data.

All that being said, as William Pursell pointed out, `awk` can make this sort of thing *trivial* [if you know how](https://learnbyexample.github.io/tips/cli-tip-9/). Using the same input file -

```
$: awk -v RS= '/outrt/{print $0 "\n"}' file
[outbound-allroutes]
include => outbound-allroutes-custom
include => outrt-1 ; test first block

[outbound-allroutes]
include => outbound-allroutes-custom
include => outrt-2 ; test embedded block

[outbound-allroutes]
include => outbound-allroutes-custom
include => outrt-3 ; test last/END block
```

Answer (score 2):

You are working *way* too hard.  What you are trying to do is utterly trivial with `awk`.  For example:

```
$ cat input
[outbound-allroutes]
include => outbound-allroutes-custom
include => bazrt-5 ; test

[outbound-allroutes]
include => outbound-allroutes-custom
include => outrt-5 ; test

[outbound-allroutes]
include => outbound-allroutes-custom
include => foort-5 ; test

[outbound-allroutes]
include => outbound-allroutes-custom
include => barrt-5 ; test
$ awk '/outrt/' RS= input
[outbound-allroutes]
include => outbound-allroutes-custom
include => outrt-5 ; test
```

Setting RS to the empty string causes awk to treat blank lines as the record separator.  `/outrt/` does a regex match and prints only the records that matches the pattern.  Don't try to find line numbers or do surgery with `grep` and `sed`; just print the records that match with `awk`.

To get the output format you seem to want, you can do things like:

```
awk '/outrt/ { printf "%s: %s\n", FILENAME, $1 }' RS= input
```

It's a little difficult to get the line number, but not impossible, and I claim you don't really care, and you don't really want to know it.  To get the recursion, wrap this in a script and use `find`.

Comment: sections are not terminated by `\n\n`. asterisk configuration file format appears to be [somewhat hairy](https://docs.asterisk.org/20/Fundamentals/Asterisk-Configuration/Asterisk-Configuration-Files/Adding-to-an-existing-section/). cf. https://github.com/asterisk/asterisk/blob/master/configs/samples/extensions.conf.sample